# how to ask if in two categorys inside if

Tags: categories, get-posts

I'm new two wordpress so sorry in advance if this question might be very basic.
Depending on which category a post is, I do some script things and I ask inside the loop in this way:

```
<?php if (has_category('category_1')):?>
   // do some stuff
<? endif; ?>
```

this works pretty fine. But how can I ask for if post has two specific categories like:

```
<?php if (has_category('category_1') && has_category('category_2'):?>
  // do some stuff
<? endif; ?>
```

this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you write it as an answer with comments. sorry as I stated I am very average.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple categories within `has_category` like so:

```
if ( has_category( array( 'category_1', 'category_2' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

However, I am not sure if this acts as `AND` or `OR`, meaning does it require that **ALL categories specified are matched**, or **one** of the X supplied (category_1 OR category_2).

In any case, your syntax should work perfectly fine. double check on the spelling perhaps?

Comment: it is working, thank you for the spelling tip! was that fault.